# FluentValidation date invalid on all dates

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datepicker, fluentvalidation

I've been working with fluentvalidation and am running into an issue where dates picked are invalid no matter what.

Here is the rule:

```
RuleFor(c => c.UserPickedDate)
  .LessThanOrEqualTo(DateTime.Now)
  .WithMessage("Cannot use a future date.");
```

The purpose of this is to restrict the user to pick either today or a previous date.

Also, this *works* when the property name is overridden, such as:

```
RuleFor(c => c.UserPickedDate.Date)
  .LessThanOrEqualTo(DateTime.Now.Date)
  .WithMessage("Cannot use a future date.");
```

This works in the sense that it invalidates any future dates, so the user cannot submit the form, but it does not display the message for some reason, while the one above does (only for all dates). When I use `.OverridePropertyName`, I am back in the same place as before, where it is invalid on all dates picked (past, present and future).

Comment: It may not be the actual root of the problem, but `DateTime.Now` is going to return a timestamp in the locale of the current process.  If this is being run on a server (as opposed to on the customer's side), that's probably not the customer's zone.  Getting `DateTime.Now.Date` would only mask the problem... and create new ones for anybody ahead of the server zone (since they may be a calendar day ahead).  Unfortunately,  messing with TimeZoneInfo wouldn't completely solve the issue...

Comment: try using `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of `DateTime.Now`. also convert the UserPickedDate to UTC. because I don't find any other issue with this code

Comment: It was fixed by adding a lambda for the DateTime object. So (c => DateTime.Now)